# Where does Orbeon store data?

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I am very new to Orbeon and XForms. I've downloaded Orbeon 4 CE and created a sample web form.

1. I have created some sample forms and I'm able to test, publish and save it. But, i don't know where the entered form data is getting stored / saved?
2. How the data integration happens?
3. Not able to see Orbeon Form Runner in v4 CE?
4. I've not configured any DB. It is mentioned like eXist DB is the native DB for orbeon.

Answer (score 0):

When creating forms with Form Builder, both the definition of the form themselves, and of the data captured when you "execute" the form are stored in the build-in eXist database. It comes bundled with Orbeon Forms, so gets used without you having to setup anything. But you can also setup Orbeon Forms to use another database:

- It could be eXist, but setup separately from Orbeon Forms.
- It could be [MySQL or Oracle](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/oracle-and-mysql-persistence-layers).
- It could be anything if you implement the Orbeon [REST persistence API](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api).

Comment: Yes, as u said exist-db comes natively with Orbeon. Thus, i didn't do any db setup or configuration. Started right away with form dev, saved-tested & published. And on the orbeon summary page, my app is listed. My question is, where is the form is stored on our local drive. I've checked the exist-db on D:\apache-tomcat-6.0.29\webapps\orbeon\WEB-INF\exist-data folder, but couldn't find my form.